# Create an sql query for two tables for a one-to-many with pivot relation conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need assistance creating a query for two tables.

1. The first table `books` already has an author (the author's name) and illustrator (illustrator) in the `author` and `illustrator` column.
2. The second table `people` also has the name of the author in the `name` column.
3. The third table `books_people` has the two columns `book_id` and `author_id` and a third column called `occupation`

This is more of a conversion from having the authors directly in the `books` table to having a separate table creating a relation between two tables (one-to-many) ( table: `books_authors` ). I would also need help making the column of that relation submit the occupation.

Books Table:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id |    title     |     author     |     artist      |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Tower of God | SIU            | SIU             |
|  2 | Zippy Ziggy  | KIM Eun-jung   | HWANG Seung-man |
|  4 | Beelzebub    | Tamura Ryuuhei | Tamura Ryuuhei  |
+----+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

People Table:

```
+-------+-----------------+
|  id   |      name       |
+-------+-----------------+
|    32 | SIU             |
|  4053 | KIM Eun-jung    |
|  4055 | HWANG Seung-man |
| 28490 | Tamura Ryuuhei  |
+-------+-----------------+
```

Books_People Table

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| comic_id | person_id |   occupation   |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| comic_id | person_id |   occupation   |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
|        1 |        32 | author, artist |
|        2 |      4053 | author         |
|        2 |      4055 | artist         |
|        4 |     28490 | author, artist |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

What im trying to do here is "create" the rows after the relations have been made.

Comment: give sample data and sample output

Comment: If the `books` table references authors and illustrators as `people` by name, then you need to fix that first.

Comment: provide a  proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @AluanHaddad it doesnt have the reference. The books table only has the name of the author ( no other columns, other than the id).

Comment: What exactly should the query you are looking for be doing?

Comment: @Terrabyte then how can you determine who the author of any book is? You should store the person's Id instead. In other words, I'm saying it should be a reference.

Comment: i have provided some data structure

Comment: For the expected results there is no need to join anything, all fields are in the Books_People table. All you need is group_concat() with a group by clause to produce the expected outcome.

Comment: @Shadow what would be the resulting query to do this?

Comment: See the duplicate topic for the solution.

Comment: anyone got a hint on how to do it for my query?

Comment: Select 
b.id,
pe.id person_id
, pe.name,
case when b.author= b.artist then cast('author,artist' as nvarchar2(200)) end||
case  when (b.author<>b.artist  and b.author=pe.name) then cast( 'author' as nvarchar2(200)) end||
case  when (b.author<>b.artist  and b.artist=pe.name) then cast( 'artist' as nvarchar2(200)) end
  occupation
from 
books b
join people pe on b.author like pe.name 

--union second sql

Comment: union 

select b.id,
pe.id person_id ,
 pe.name ,
case when b.author= b.artist then cast('author,artist' as nvarchar2(200)) end||
case  when (b.author<>b.artist  and b.author=pe.name) then cast( 'author' as nvarchar2(200)) end||
case  when (b.author<>b.artist  and b.artist=pe.name) then cast( 'artist' as nvarchar2(200)) end
  occupation
from 
books b
join people pe on b.artist like pe.name
where b.author not like b.artist

Comment: this works in oracle sql

Comment: @SevincQurbanovado Are you able to provide a mysql equivalent please?

Comment: nvm i figured it out, but how do i create rows after i've gone ahead and set the groupings